# MySQL query for movies with multiple genres using an intermediary table

Tags: mysql, sql

I hardly use MySQL so I'm very new to this. My end goal is to have a list that I can put into Java which contains a movie id, movie name, and list of genres. I'm just trying to figure out an SQL query (so I can parse the other things later). I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `year` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `genres_in_movies` (
  `genre_id` int NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genres`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Lets say my tables have the following values:

```
MOVIES
------
1  Zoolander      2001
2  Citizen Kane   1941
3  Psycho         1960

GENRES
------
1  Comedy
2  Horror
3  Drama
4  Suspense
5  Romance
6  Documentary

GENRES_IN_MOVIES (genre_id, movie_id)
------
1  1  -- Comedy   - Zoolander
3  2  -- Drama    - Citizen Kane
4  2  -- Suspense - Citizen Kane
2  3  -- Horror   - Psycho
5  3  -- Romance  - Psycho
4  3  -- Suspense - Psycho
```

I want the following output with my query:

```
MOVIE LIST
------
1  Zoolander     2001  Comedy
2  Citizen Kane  1949  Drama, Suspense
3  Psycho        1960  Horror, Romance, Suspense
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT movies.*, genres.name
FROM movies 
INNER JOIN genres_in_movies ON genres_in_movies.movie_id = movies.id
INNER JOIN genres ON genres_in_movies.genre_id = genres.id
GROUP BY movies.title;
```

But it will only give me one genre name. So it looks like this:

```
MOVIE LIST
------
1  Zoolander     2001  Comedy
2  Citizen Kane  1949  Drama
3  Psycho        1960  Horror
```

How can I retrieve all the genres?

Comment: Have you considered group_concat?

Comment: @jarlh I'll look that up, I'm honestly very new to SQL still

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." (However, older MySQL versions don't care, but newer do!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` to put multiple values together

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, m.year,
       group_concat(g.name) as genres
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN genres_in_movies ON gm.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN genres ON gm.genre_id = g.id
GROUP BY m.id, m.title, m.year
```